# Eclipse with SDCC plug in - always has an error of java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: eclipse, plugins, nullpointerexception, sdcc

I had installed latest Eclipse IDE with C/C++, installed SDCC and put the net.souurceforge.eclipsesdcc.1.0.0 plugin into the Eclipse Plugins & Features folder.  When startup Eclipse, start to create a project using MC51 family (SDCC) with SDCC Tools Chain, click "Finish", it always come up with an error of java.lang.NullPointerException.  I do the same thing on both Windows Vista and Windows XP machine, same problem.

Am I missing something on the setting?

Thank you so much in advance.

Martin

Answer (score 3):

Plugin can't to find os specific program (sh.exe).
Try to copy folder "os" from folder "net.sourceforge.eclipsesdcc.win32_1.0.0" into forder "net.sourceforge.eclipsesdcc_1.0.0".

Answer (score 3):

The solutions above were very helpful - thanks, everyone!  To clarify, I had to use the answers from both Alexander.P and Urgo to be able to successfully create an MCS51 family (SDCC) project in Eclipse.  Here's what I did ...

1. Installed 32 bit version of Eclipse for Windows.
2. Installed eclipseSDCC plugin.
3. Copied "os" folder from "Eclipse\plugins\net.sourceforge.eclipsesdcc.win32_1.0.0" to "Eclipse\plugins\net.sourceforge.eclipsesdcc_1.0.0".
4. Set project to use internal builder: Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Builder Settings tab -> Builder type = Internal builder.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem.I solved this problem with this file http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-sdcc/files/Eclipse%203.1.x/eclipseSDCC-1.0.0/net.sourceforge.eclipsesdcc-1.0.0-win32.x86.zip/download
İ think this problem was wrong platform selection.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the 32-bit version of Eclipse in Windows. That's the only one that worked for me to get SDCC Eclipse plugin working. With the 64-bit version I would get the same NullPointerException.

As an extra note, once the project is setup I also needed to right-click on the project in Eclipse then go Properties -> C/C++ Build, then go to the "Builder Settings" tab and change "Builder type" to Internal Builder.