# Eclipse 4.2.1 SDCC plugin can't create MCS51 project

Tags: eclipse-plugin, sdcc

I'm running Eclipse 4.2.1 on 64-bit Windows 7. I have the Eclipse CDT plugin installed and can make C/C++ projects. I have sdcc installed (get a response on CL with `sdcc --version`). I have downloaded this version of the plugin:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-sdcc/files/latest/download?source=dlp

Unzipped, and put all the contents of the features and plugins folders in to my corresponding Eclipse install's features and plugins folders.  (followed instructions from http://mihirknows.blogspot.com/2007/10/installing-sdcc-under-eclipse.html).

I restart Eclipse, go to File>New>C Project. Select MCS51 family (SDCC) under Project type and SDCC Tool Chain under Toolchains. Click next, leave Release and Debug selected, click Finish. Error Creating Project box pops up. Says Project cannot be created Reason: Internal Error: I click on the Details button and it says java.lang.NullPointer.Exception. (Would have included a screencap, but I no haz the reputation yet > _<)

I've also seen this post:
[Eclipse with SDCC plug in - always has an error of java.lang.NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672785/eclipse-with-sdcc-plug-in-always-has-an-error-of-java-lang-nullpointerexceptio)
They only suggest downloading the same zip I used.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and Alexander.P's answer in [Eclipse with SDCC plug in - always has an error of java.lang.NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672785/eclipse-with-sdcc-plug-in-always-has-an-error-of-java-lang-nullpointerexceptio) did the trick for me. SDCC 3.4 and Eclipse Luna 4.4.1.

Answer (score 0):

Well.. I managed it to get SDCC run on a Windows 7 32-bit machine. I recommend you to create a new project in an Eclipse where you didn't install the plugin and debug through the source code. That's what I did so I could eliminate a few errors and get it run.

Edit:
You also will have to replace the sh.exe by that one that is used by Cygwin since that sh.exe that comes with the SDCC plugin seems to crash when you start to build.